Flutter CustomSearchDelegate with Riverpod
I'm developing a flutter app with riverpod as state management / provider.
I do have a tipsProvider which provides me with a List of tips.
final tipsProvider = FutureProvider.autoDispose<List<Tip>>((ref) async { ... }

Now I'm trying to implement a global search functionality. I like the way the Material SearchDelegate works.
Therefore I implement a class CustomSearchDelegate extends SearchDelegate<List<Tip>>
At the same time I was following the search as we type tutorial from riverpod.
This tutorial implements new providers:
final searchFieldProvider = StateProvider<String>((ref) => '');
final searchProvider = FutureProvider.autoDispose<List<Tip>>((ref) async {
final search = ref.watch(searchFieldProvider);
// do the search magic here 
// propably accessing the tipProvider and filtering the results
...
}

The problem:
In the tutorial they use a TextField and its callback method to update the StateProvider:
TextField(
        onChanged: (value) =>
            ref.read(searchFieldProvider.notifier).state = value,
      ),

By using the SearchDelegate I don't have access to the Search Text Field / onChanged method. I can use the buildSuggestions method, which is called on change of the search.
But if i try to update the StateProvider inside the buildSuggestions:
  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer(
      builder: (context, ref, _) {
        ref.read(searchFieldProvider.notifier).state = query;
      });
  }

I get the following error during runtime:

So i assume i can`t update the state inside the build method.
I'm not quite sure how i can use the solution from the error message:

modifying provider outside widget life-cycle => difficult, how can i get access to it inside the SearchDelegate?
delay modification. Not quite sure how to that and where.

Any tips on combining riverpod and SearchDelegate? I do find suprisingly less information on that.
